# Does redux-persist persist/save data in between App updates?

Tags: react-native, redux-persist

On my phone when I'm doing debugging...if I save something on redux-persist, then I change some code and save and run: `npx react-native run-android`...when the new version of the app loads I still can see the data I have saved previously.

Does this mean redux-presist is good as a database substitute so that even after App updates in the Appstore then the data saved will still be in the device and accessible by the updated App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it saves the store into `AsyncStorage` which uses the sandbox of your app which can be only accessed by your app (app id and only that id can access that sandbox) no matter which version. It is different, I would not consider it as a substitute but rather as a supplement to a data base. That doesn't mean that you can't try to use it as such.

Comment: Sounds like for practical purposes one can just use redux-persist as a database then since it probably can persist data in between updates....